# What is the use of configuring management.properties in profiling remote JVM

Tags: jvm, profiling, jmx, jconsole, jvisualvm

It is required to configure **management.properties** in 'jre_home\lib\management' to enable remote monitoring. But even after configuring the required properties below

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<portNum>
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I was not able to connect to remote JVM with the : given using JConsole or JVisualVM. So in addition to this configuration do I need to make any code changes to enable remote JVM profiling (like creating a JMX server)?

Since i'm configuring management.properties, that will affect all java application using that JRE. So in that context how can profile each application?

So in summary, is it possible to profile a remote JVM by configuring some properties and not making any code changes?

Answer (score 2):

What version of JDK do you use? In pre JDK 1.6 version you should specify -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote or -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port in the application you want to monitor with JConsole.
In JDK 1.6 it should work unless you specify -XX:-DisableAttachMechanism.